# .net 6 upgrade: unit tests fail on build server

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-6.0

Unfortunately I have another strange behavior after the .net 6 upgrade.
On my local machine (with the .net 6 sdk installed) everything works fine, can be built and the unit tests run.

On the build server the same unit tests fail with the following exception:

> ```
>  Test method Module.Test.Jobs.Razor.FilePathRenderer_Test.Render_WithDateTimeNow_ReturnsFormattedString threw exception: 
>  System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit.EmitOptions..ctor(Boolean, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit.DebugInformationFormat, System.String, System.String, Int32, UInt64, Boolean, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SubsystemVersion, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit.InstrumentationKind>, System.Nullable`1<System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName>, System.Text.Encoding, System.Text.Encoding)'.
> ```

The package `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common` had been a problem locally when upgrading because of a version conflict. It said that I had to install version 4.0.0 manually to the project which I did (this fixed the build error locally but the tests on the build server fail):

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" Version="4.0.0" />
```

Have you experienced this problem before and know what I could do to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you're not including your transitive (but still top-level) dependencies in your publish steps. Ensure that the `icrosoft.CodeAnalysis.Common` package is **directly** referenced by **all** projects in your solution (yes, this is overkill, but it will work, you can trim it back afterwards).

Comment: btw, `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common` is now on `4.1.0`, you might want to consider updating.

Comment: I'd confirm what your agent (e.g. is it something like `windows-2022` or 'windows-latest') is that runs the test.